# Enable HTTPS for Jfrog Artifactory without reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, https, artifactory

I am trying to configure Artifactory to use HTTPS without the need for a reverse proxy.
My Artifactory instance is set on a docker container.

$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml:

```
artifactory:
    tomcat:
        httpsConnector:
            enabled: true
            port: 8443
            certificateFile: "/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/ssl/arti-test.crt"
            certificateKeyFile: "/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/ssl/arti-test.key"
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  artifactory:
    image: releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:latest
    container_name: artifactory
    ports:
      - 443:8443
```

When trying to reach the web site I get: This site can’t be reached

What is the procedure to achieve HTTPS artifactory on container without reverse proxy?

Comment: Why do you use port 8443 not 443 in docker-compose?

Comment: Why does it matter? its an internal port of the application..

Comment: Please provide more information on the error. Look in the logs or container's stdout to find errors that can explain it.
Also, see documentation: 
(1) https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/set-tls-on-the-jfrog-platform 
(2) https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-debug-ssl-issues-with-artifactory/tomcat-level-ssl-issues 
(3) https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-enable-tls-within-the-jfrog-platform-using-custom-certificates/steps-to-enable-tls-with-customer-certificate

Answer (score 1):

According to the information above this if for Artifactory version 7.x, in this case, note that the UI and Artifactory are two separate services.
If you'd like to reach the platform's UI via HTTPS without a reverse proxy it will be required to enable TLS in the [Access YAML Configuration](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/access-yaml-configuration).
You may refer to this [documentation page](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/using-access-as-a-certificate-authority) for reference and instructions

Comment: Hi
I followed the instruction but the application is not up:
`Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception`

In the instruction it says: The certificate's subject must match the property shared.node.ip from system.yaml
Well, the cert wasnt created against an IP address but an FQDN in CN, should I insert the FQDN in shared.node.ip or since I dont have the IP in the cert I can not set HTTPS?

Comment: You are correct. For some (seemingly) stupid reason, Artifactory requires the configured certificate's Subject Common Name to be the IP address of the Artifactory node being secured with TLS. This has nothing to do with the TLS connection itself (it appears) but is something that Artifactory uses internally, I believe for when it's running in a HA configuration. This bit me, too, as I know a thing or two about PKI and understood that the Subject Common Name is really not a field that is used in the TLS handshake between browsers and web servers these days.